# Does Ron Weasley successfully cast a spell "on camera" in books 2 through 6?

Tags: harry-potter

In Book 1, we see Ron Weasley successfully cast a spell when the Trio is facing the troll:

> Hermione had sunk to the floor in fright; Ron pulled out his own wand -- not knowing what he was going to do he heard himself cry the first spell that came into his head: *'Wingardium Leviosa!'*
>
> The club flew suddenly out of the troll's hand, rose high, high up into the air, slowly turned over -- and dropped, with a sickening crack, onto its owner's head.
>
> *Philosopher's Stone* -- Bloomsbury -- chapter 10, *Hallowe'en*

In Book 7, we see Ron cast spells, such as on this occasion when the Trio are discussing Moody's uncertain fate after his failure to arrive at The Burrow:

> But with a great creaking of rusty bedsprings Ron bounded off the bed and got there first. One arm around Hermione, he fished in his jeans pocket and withdrew a revolting-looking handkerchief that he had used to clean out the oven earlier. Hastily pulling out his wand, he pointed it at the rag and said, *'Tergeo.'*
>
> The wand siphoned off most of the grease. Looking rather pleased with himself, Ron handed the slightly smoking handkerchief to Hermione.
>
> *Deathly Hallows* -- Bloomsbury -- chapter 6, *The Ghoul in Pyjamas*

Question: In books 2 through 6, do we ever seen Ron successfully cast a spell "on camera"?  That is, do we actually see him say the incantation -- assuming a verbal spell -- and the spell works properly?

(Obviously, to get through school, Ron must have successfully performed spells on a regular basis, but do we ever actually see it happen in a scene being portrayed?)

Comment: If Draco Malfoy had an SE account, this is the type of question he'd ask ;-)

Comment: @tonysdg Perhaps I should suggest he get one. ;)

Comment: Sorely tempted to post pictures of the films just to annoy purists...

Comment: In the 6th movie at least, he accidentally starts making it snow in Hogwarts.

Comment: *Ahem*. I believe the spell is ["Tergeo"](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Tergeo). ;-)

Comment: @ScottMilner Corrected, thanks! I don't suppose I can blame autocorrect for that one...? :-)

Comment: Does his slug-vomiting curse count? Didn't curse Malfoy like he had planned, but it certainly worked on him.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

#### *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*

I'm not sure if this counts as a spell:

> "Ron unlocked the cavernous boot with a series of taps from his wand. They heaved their trunks back in, put Hedwig on the back seat and got into the front.
> 'Check no one's watching,' said Ron, starting the ignition with another tap of his wand."

Then Ron's wand breaks:

> "My wand," said Ron, in a shaky voice. "Look at my wand." It had snapped, almost in two; the tip was dangling limply, held on by a few splinters.

After that we don't see him successfully cast a spell for the rest of the year.

#### *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*

> "Excellent! Ron, you next!"
> Ron leapt forward.
> *Crack*!
> Quite a few people screamed. A giant spider, six feet tall and covered in hair, was advancing on Ron, clicking its pincers menacingly. For a moment, Harry thought Ron had frozen. Then –
> "Riddikulus!" bellowed Ron, and the spider's legs vanished. It rolled over and over; Lavender Brown squealed and ran out of its way and it came to a halt at Harry's feet. He raised his wand, ready, but –
> "Here!" shouted Professor Lupin suddenly, hurrying forward.

He also successfully cast Lumos:

> Ron pulled out his wand and muttered, "Lumos!"
> A beam of light fell across the grass, hit the bottom of a tree and illuminated its branches; there, crouching amongst the budding leaves, was Crookshanks.

As well as possibly Expelliarmus, although both Harry and Hermione cast it at the same time so it's less clear that Ron himself was successful:

> "Expelliarmus!" he yelled – except that his wasn't the only voice that shouted. There was a blast that made the door rattle on its hinges; Snape was lifted off his feet and slammed into the wall, then slid down it to the floor, a trickle of blood oozing from under his hair. He had been knocked out.
> Harry looked around. Both Ron and Hermione had tried to disarm Snape at exactly the same moment. Snape's wand soared in a high arc and landed on the bed next to Crookshanks.

#### *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

Ron successfully cast Lumos again:

> "Fred and George can't have gone that far," said Ron, pulling out his wand, lighting it like Hermione, and squinting up the path.

Then he used some sort of spell that creates sparks:

> "Don' frighten him, now!" Hagrid shouted, as Ron and Harry used their wands to shoot jets of fiery sparks at the Skrewt, which was advancing menacingly on them, its sting arched, quivering, over its back. "Jus' try an' slip the rope round his sting, so he won' hurt any o' the others!"

He casts a Banishing Charm:

> "Snape said Moody's searched his office as well?" Ron whispered, his eyes alight with interest as he Banished a cushion with a sweep of his wand (it soared into the air and knocked Parvati's hat off).

Then another Banishing Charm:

> "What?" said Ron, his eyes widening, his next cushion spinning high into the air, ricocheting off the chandelier and dropping heavily onto Flitwick's desk.

He casts an Impediment Jinx:

> "Good training for when we're all Aurors," said Ron excitedly, attempting the Impediment Jinx on a wasp that had buzzed into the room, and making it stop dead in mid-air.

He also casts an unidentifiable hex, though it's unclear whether it's successful:

> He, Ron and Hermione were on their feet, all three of them having used a different hex. Nor were they the only ones to have done so.

#### Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix:

Ron *somewhat* successfully vanished a mouse:

> “She did, however, take many more notes while sitting in her corner, and when Professor McGonagall finally told them all to pack away, she rose with a grim expression on her face.
> ‘Well, it’s a start,’ said Ron, holding up a long wriggling mouse-tail and dropping it back into the box Lavender was passing around.”

He successfully, although *stupidly*, casts Accio on a brain in a tank at the Department of Mysteries:

> “Honest, Harry, they’re brains – look – Accio brain!’
> The scene seemed momentarily frozen. Harry, Ginny and Neville and each of the Death Eaters turned in spite of themselves to watch the top of the tank as a brain burst from the green liquid like a leaping fish: for a moment it seemed suspended in midair, then it soared towards Ron, spinning as it came, and what looked like ribbons of moving images flew from it, unravelling like rolls of film –”

Ron also presumably casts spells in Dumbledore's Army, such as Expelliarmus, Impedimenta, and Expecto Patronum, but none are specifically shown at the time as being his.

Comment: What about five and six?

Comment: @Adamant I'm looking through them, this is taking a while. I'm looking for every mention of Ron, then checking if he casts a spell.

Comment: Did they decide to give the spider rollerskates in the movies to prevent kids pulling legs off spiders afterwards?

Comment: @pyro a spider’s body would be unlikely to roll, perhaps that’s the issue?

Comment: @pyro A massive amount of details and larger plot points were changed for the films, presumably to make it more visually interesting, or some such excuse. I wouldn't bother trying to rationalise this.

Comment: This is an exceptionally well-researched answer, thanks Bellatrix. I was expecting people to bring up 1 or 2 counter-examples each.

Comment: @Bellatrix I hope you are using  a script and not performing it by hand. In both case, good job!

Comment: @aloisdg I'm searching it using iBooks. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! It would be awesome to see this expanded to books 5 and 6 as well. It's interesting that there actually are a number of instances of Ron casting spells -- but most of them omit a spoken incantation quote that's attributed specifically to Ron, which is probably why they escaped my notice.

Comment: I agree it's well-researched. I looked through the books for like an hour, and found only one case of Ron casting a spell. You found a lot more, although only two more that definitely satisfies the criteria in the question “we actually see him say the incantation […] and the spell works properly”.

Answer (score 11):

To add to Bellatrix' excellent answer:

**Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix**:

He's one of Harry's support troupe (along with Hermione, Neville, Ginny and Luna) casting Reducto in the Ministry fight.

> 'NOW!' yelled Harry.
>
> Five different voices behind him bellowed, 'REDUCTO!' Five curses flew in five different directions and the shelves opposite them exploded as they hit [...]

While not on camera, this mention after a DA session gets an honorary mention for besting Hermione:

> 'That was really, really good, Harry,' said Hermione, when finally it was just her, Harry and Ron who were left.
>
> 'Yeah, it was!' said Ron enthusiastically, as they slipped out of the door and watched it melt back into stone behind them. 'Did you see me disarm Hermione, Harry?'
>
> 'Only once,' said Hermione, stung. 'I got you loads more than you got me -'

**Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince**:

Harry and Ron cast *Specialis revelio* in Potions, but it's unclear whether it works:

> Hermione was now waving her wand enthusiastically over her cauldron. Unfortunately, they could not copy the spell she was doing because she was now so good at non-verbal incantations that she did not need to say the words aloud. Ernie Macmillan, however, was mutterin, '*Specialis revelio!* over his cauldron, which sounded impressive, so Harry and Ron hastened to imitate him.

He casts an unidentified spell at Ginny but misses:

> 'You don't know what you're talking about!' Ron roared, trying to get a clear shot at Ginny around Harry, who was now standing in front of her with his arms outstretched. [...]
>
> A streak of orange light flew under Harry's left arm and missed Ginny by inches [...]